# COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES and Retina graphics for a WebView

Tags: xcode, macos, retina-display, appkit

We have an Xcode project that includes both Retina graphics for a NIB-based UI and a WebView UI. This project builds an app for the Mac.

The project uses two separate build phases to move these graphics into the final app. The first is the traditional Copy Bundle Resource which gets both the 1x and 2x graphics into the application package. The second is a Copy Files build phase which copies the web graphics into a separate Resources destination with a "graphics" subpath.

(This avoids some naming conflicts and lets the web designer use a familiar "graphics/whatever.png" path.)

When building this project, we get a Dependency Analysis Error that says:

> Multi-representation image 'whatever@2x.png' cannot be processed by a
>   Copy Files build phase - try a Copy Resources build phase, or disable
>   COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES.

It's easy enough to turn off the Deployment Build Setting called "Combine High Resolution Artwork", but this affects the graphics used in the NIB-based UI as well as the ones in the WebView UI. With the option turned on, `button.png` and `button@2x.png` get combined into a `button.tiff` in the application package's Resource folder. Without it, the original names are used.

As far as I can tell, the application behaves normally, but since COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES is set on by default, I suspect there is some benefit to deploying the graphics as a single file (faster to load and cache, perhaps.)

Ideally, I'd like to only disable COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES during the Copy Files build phase. I can't figure out a way to do this, hopefully someone else here can...

**Update 8/27/2012**

For this particular application, the easiest way to fix the problem was to replace all HTML images with the 2x version. Since the  tags specify a width and a height, the images are scaled down by 50% on a non-Retina device. The quality is fine and since they're being loaded from the local filesystem there's not perceivable performance impact.

**Update 8/28/2012**

Another approach we took was with naming conventions. Some HTML images are specified using CSS (with a media query selecting the Retina or non-Retina version.) To avoid problems with these images being combined into a single HiDPI image, we used whatever.png and whatever_retina.png.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do it is a bit of a hack, but no one else has answered so as it should work for you.

I suggest you use an xcconfig file on your target (target.xcconfig) to specify the settings you want changed, then have build scripts before/after the phase which replace the current xcconfig with one of two versions (target-on.xcconfig, target-off.xcconfig). This should work, however Xcode may not update the xcconfig file until later (I'm not in a position to check at the moment), you'll have to check.

I'll leave it up to you to figure out the details. More details on (a less hackish variation) of this approach, and how to set it up, can be found at my [blog](http://therealbnut.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/setting-xcode-4-0-environment-variables-from-a-script/).

Comment: If this doesn't work and you're building from _xcodebuild_ you can use the `-xcconfig` parameter to specify which version you want.